# How to do multiple regression with limited experience and (hopefully) excel?

Tags: logistic, multivariate-analysis, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, excel

I am doing a study of how legal need relates to a number of predictors.

Outcome Variable:  Legal Need (Yes or No)
Possible Predictors:  Age, Gender, Race, Ethnicity, Language, Clinic, Insurance Status.
Predictors based on bivariate analysis:  Age, Language, Clinic, Insurance Status.  All ORs were around 1.6 and were significant, typical 95CI between 1.2-2.0.
Number of subjects:  8803

I suspect that the one variable that is going to fall out of a multiple regression analysis would be Clinic, as the Asthma Clinic (vs the well-visit clinic) has in general, older children who don't speak English and are more on Medicaid (the other predictors from bivariate analysis).

Knowing all of this, I still can't figure out how to run a multiple regression in Excel.

I keep getting Pearson's coefficients like 0.06, which it then says is significant.

Either way I think I need to go beyond this, maybe a stepwise forward or backward analysis?

It's difficult for me to grasp when the outcome is a 0 (no) or 1 (yes), this doesn't really result in anything linear when the percent "yes's" are typically in the 15-30% range.

Am I missing something?  Besides years of stats training?

Comment: As BWilliams writes, doing these types of problem in Excel is like showing up to the Tour de France with a tricycle.

Try R or - if that makes life a bit difficult - give Python a go (with packages like scipy / numpy etc).

I suspect R is your best bet.

Answer (score 6):

> Number of subjects: 8803 Outcome Variable: Legal Need (Yes or No)

See the end, but I will deal with side issues first.

> How to do multiple regression with ... excel?

The easiest way to do multiple regression in Excel is to install the Data Analysis Toolpack, which should have come with Excel but by default isn't installed.

> I keep getting Pearson's coefficients like 0.06, which it then says is significant

Why does this surprise you?

(And by a 'Pearson coefficient' are you referring to $R$ or $R^2$?)

> Either way I think I need to go beyond this, maybe a stepwise forward or backward analysis?

Why? What are you trying to achieve?

> It's difficult for me to grasp when the outcome is a 0 (no) or 1 (yes), this doesn't really result in anything linear when the percent "yes's" are typically in the 15-30% range. Am I missing something?

You should *start* with asking about this issue. It's by far the most critical.

Multiple regression is not the right tool for this problem. You likely need to use logistic regression, which would model a function of the probability of a 'yes' in terms of a linear function of the predictors.

So where multiple regression would fit a model like $Y_i = x_i^T\beta + \epsilon_i$ with independent, identically distributed $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, a logistic regression would model the $Y_i$ as independent *Bernoulli* random variables, where if $p_i = P(Y_i=1)$, then the probability is modelled as a function of predictors like so: $\log(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}) = x_i^T\beta$.

See [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) (and also [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) of which the Bernoulli is a special case).

Logistic regression is a special case of Generalized Linear Models (GLMs).

As an example of the resources that are available, John Fox has some online course materials [here](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/SPIDA/index.html) that discuss linear models (such as multiple regression) and then [simple logit](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/SPIDA/logit-models-notes.pdf) models (simple case of what we're talking about) before going onto the multiple-regression version. Then later, his materials go on to [GLMs more generally](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/SPIDA/GLMs-notes.pdf).

If you want a text that covers the territory, maybe [this](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/index.html) one, though there are lots of good ones out there; different books suit different people.

You're not going to manage to implement logistic regression in vanilla Excel unless you know a lot more about things than you do (though there are no doubt Add-In packages you can buy).

You're best off using something actually designed for this sort of analysis.

It will take some time and effort to get up to speed (if you don't understand multiple regression well, you'll need to get some background before you'll find logistic regression models making much sense), and then you'll need to learn a package that will fit the model.

R is free and does this sort of thing pretty easily. If you google *logistic regression in R* you can even find a few videos as well as various beginner* level documents.

* beginner to logistic regression, not beginner to statistics

In R a multiple regression model could be fitted like this:

```
 lm(outcome ~ age + gender + race)
```

(or whatever variables are in your model, for some outcome suited to multiple regression)

Whereas a logistic regression model could be fitted like so:

```
 glm(legal.need ~ age + gender + race, family=binomial)
```

- as you see, it's not actually much different to specify the model.

If you decide to go the R route, note that there are lots of *beginner resources for R* (google that italicized phrase for example). [R also has its own tag on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)

Finally, there are some other questions here on stats.stackexchange.com that might help a little, such as this one:

[Logistic vs linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44569/logistic-vs-linear-regression)

If you have some specific followup questions, I'd be happy to try to tackle them.

Comment: Kudos, terrific answer, except I think you're underestimating how much work it will take to master logistic regression, in R no less.  Just getting the data into R and then making sure variables are appropriately treated as continuous or categorical can take a nontrivial amount of time to learn.  Then there are all the differences between logistic and linear regression in the way results are interpreted, the way the model/solution is evaluated, etc. This may be one of those occasions when hiring a statistical consultant is the best bet.

Comment: @rolando2 Actually I devoted a paragraph to trying to explain just how large the task appeared to be (without being downbeat about it). I don't think I underestimate it at all, but sometimes emphasis is hard to convey.

Answer (score 4):

This is a binomial model and will not be particularly fun to implement in Excel.
I would recommend something like R where you could then account for the binomial distribution using a generalized linear model.

à la

```
fit <- glm(outcome~age+gender+race, data = data, family= binomial)
```

You could run each model and compare them with AIC.